# Different price for role

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

My question is similar to others, but not exactly the same. All the other answers have a specific discount (%) amount for Members, but my client needs to be able to set a totally different, specific price for each of their art classes for members, that is, there is no specific rule that applies to all classes equally. So, I created a Member Price field to hold each unique reduced price, but I'm not sure which action in the dropdown would switch out the base price for the price in that field.

Answer (score 1):

It was a strange flow of events, but the question was relevant to Ubercart, which I was wrong not to mention in the original post. It took doing research for a Drupal Commerce install to find the path to the answer for Ubercart!

The answer was the Price per Role module. Part of the project requirements were that the "member" viewer should be able to see the original price. As a workaround, we actually had to set up a special fields so that both prices could show! Yes, this could have been done with coding, but the client doesn't have a budget for coding.